# Phonegap doesn't show alert

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova, alert

why phonegap doesn't show alert notification ? (running on iPhone 5.1.1 , phonegap phonegap-2.1.0-0-g26d211b, mountain lion 10.8.2, xcode 4.4.1)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/css/apple.css" title="jQTouch">
<script src="src/lib/zepto.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="cordova-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="src/jqtouch.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     try
     {
        navigator.notification.alert('Hello', ok, 'Title', 'Button!');  
     }
     catch(e)
     {
        alert("doesn't support!!");
     }
    }
    function ok() {}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are trying to show an alert before phonegap/cordova framework is loaded.

***$(document).ready(function(){*** is not going to help you here, you must use this event to check if phonegap is successfully loaded:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
}
```

More about this event: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html

> PhoneGap consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the
>   native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However,
>   JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web
>   application could, potentially, call a PhoneGap JavaScript function
>   before it is loaded.