# PhoneGap Build deviceready event not firing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm building an app with PhoneGap build and I'm trying to get the deviceready event to fire, based on Adobe's documentation: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready

I've researched this issue and found that many people have successfully overcome it. I've tried the following things:

I've added the following lines to my Index.html: (I've also tried adding cordova.js)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () { alert("Device Ready is Working"); }, false);
</script>
```

I've added the following to my config.xml file:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
```

The app loads up and runs just fine, but no deviceready alert. I've tried it on my Asus Transformer and Kindle Fire without success.

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Stories">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
    <meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="615522017730.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" />
    <meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />

    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/Lib/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/Lib/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/Core.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/Mobile.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Lib/lodash.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Lib/ui-bootstrap-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/App/Core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/App/Stories.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/App.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Controllers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Directives.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Services.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/BSDirectives.js"></script>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Plugins/PushNotification.js"></script>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () { alert("Device Ready is Working"); }, false);
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            // TODO: Fix Channel location
            FB.init({
                channelUrl: 'http://localhost:49499/stories/FBChannel.html',
                appId: '474111489382243',
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            });
        };
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var po = document.createElement('script');
            po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=render';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<widget 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
id="com.asd.sdf" 
versionCode="1.0" 
version="1.0">
<name>asd</name>
<description>asd</description>
<author href="asd" email="asd">asd</author>
<access origin="*" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
</widget>
```

Comment: It may just that the alert is no coming up, alerts are done via phonegap. You need to be able to debug. Try Weinre http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest or on IOS you can hook the enulator up to Safari http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html. You need to see what the JS console is saying otherwise its super tricky to get a handle on things.

Comment: are you checkin in web browser ??

Comment: Create a new project. The default template loads a graphic that blinks until the deviceready event is fired and then tells you you're good to go. As poperob says, an alert is not the way to test the event handler.

Comment: You looked up a very old version of the documentation. Be sure to always select "edge" on the upper right on the Phonegap documentation page. The correct link to the current documentation would be [this one](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready)

Comment: Thank you for the comments, guys. poperob and kindasimple got me on the right track. The alert just wasn't firing. I rewrote some of my code to change CSS on the page rather than show an alert and I'm seeing the results I expected. Can you explain to me why the alert wouldn't fire?

Raj: No, it was via a device, as my question states.
qefzec: Thank you for the updated link. The implementation looks exactly the same as in my question, though. Thank you, however, for passing along the knowledge of that dropdown :)

Answer (score -1):

I think this answer looks good -> [Phonegap doesn't show alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026236/phonegap-doesnt-show-alert)

*"Because you are trying to show an alert before phonegap/cordova framework is loaded.
$(document).ready(function(){ is not going to help you here, you must use this event to check if phonegap is successfully loaded"*

```
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the OP's code? You have only created a separate callback function but I believe it will work exactly the same.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't actually use a jQuery ready event at all, and it is in fact the same as my code but with a callback. My question is why the alert doesn't fire after Cordova is ready. Instead of an alert I had to use UI element changes or Weinre to relay the device ready status.